# newrelic python agent issue

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, newrelic

I have 3 standalone python applications in python Virtual env in mog_wsgi modein same server. I installed newrelic in 1st application python virtual environment and its showing fine in newrelic GUI page.

when i followed and installed same thing for 2nd and 3rd application in respective python Virtual env. but these 2 applications are not showing in Newrelic GUI application page.

For all 3 applications  log file is not updating from starting.

Please help me out to configure and integrate multiple python apps which are hosted in a single server python env.

below are steps that i have followed.

centos OS

### Install the New Relic Python agent in apps virtual env

```
source <virtual path>
pip install newrelic
pip freeze
```

### Generate config file:

```
 cd /etc/newrelic/
 newrelic-admin generate-config <Licence Key> newrelic.ini
```

### Validate the conf file:

```
newrelic-admin validate-config newrelic.ini
```

### Configure the variables in conf file

```
logfile = log file name
loglevel=info
app_name = name
```

### Integrate the appliactions mod_wsgi file with NewRelic:

Adding below in wsgi.py file

```
vi wsgi.py
import newrelic.agent
newrelic.agent.initialize('/etc/newrelic/newrelic.ini')
```

installed newrelic version is "newrelic==2.12.0.10"

Please help me.

Thank you,
subhani466@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

I know that you have posted this a while ago, but the solution I've found was to install newrelic `pip install newrelic` outside of virtual envs.

Anyone that is facing this issue just install new relic outside the virtual envs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on your setup. If you have all three Python apps in the same virtual environment and you're using newrelic.ini for all three, then all three applications will report to the same UI listing. You need to either name the config files differently (newrelic.ini, newrelic2.ini, newrelic3.ini) and reference them likewise, or split the applications into separate virtual environments.

As for the log files not writing, it sounds like you don't have user rights to that directory. You can read more about this in the New Relic docs, here: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/python/python-agent-logging

> The path provided for 'log_file' should be writable to the user that
>   your application runs as. If using Apache/mod_wsgi that would usually
>   be the Apache user which has restricted access to the filesystem. You
>   might therefore need to create a special directory into which the log
>   file can be placed which is writable to the Apache user. Because the
>   current working directory of an application could be anything, it is
>   recommended that an absolute path and not a relative path be used.

If you need more help, please open a ticket with us at http://support.newrelic.com

Comment: I have configured 3 apps in 3 different python virtual environment in a single machine and as you said i have named config files differently w.r.t application. still i am facing the same prob. Reg Logs issue, apache user have write access to that logs directory.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using one config file for three applications.
They all have the same `app_name`.
Therefore, you have one APM displayed in the UI.

Remove the `app_name` line from `newrelic.ini` and pass a unique variable `NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME` to each app.